# When do methods like JNI GetDoubleArrayElements set isCopy to true or false?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, java-native-interface, native

When would the VM pin vs copy the arrays involved here?

If you want to minimize memory usage can you force a pin vs a copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more a matter of which JVM implementation does copying and which does pinning, not what runtime conditions might determine that choice, although I can certainly imagine that say an object in permgen space might be more amenable to being pinned than a brand new one.

The decision is the JVM's, not yours.